# How to change PhantomJS viewport width in grunt-contrib-jasmine?

Tags: gruntjs, phantomjs, jasmine-jquery

I'm using Grunt to run my tests of my responsive website. Grunt-contrib-jasmine is using PhantomJS to run the webpages. I noticed that the default viewport width is 400px. However I'd like to test my big-screen behavior as well. How do I change the viewport width of PhantomJS?

Many thanks.

My Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        cssmin: {
            css: {
                src: 'css/common/page.css',
                dest: 'css/common/page.min.css'
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            options: {
                browser: true,
                curly: true,
                eqeqeq: true,
                eqnull: true,
                funcscope: true,
                globals: {
                    jQuery: true
                },
                loopfunc: true,
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish'),
                smarttabs: true,
                shadow: true
            },
            all: ['Gruntfile.js', 'js/default.j s', 'js/utils.js', 'tests/jasmine-standalone-2.0.0/spec/*.js']
        },
        jasmine: {
            obpjs: {
                src: 'tests/jasmine-standalone-2.0.0/src/*.js',
                options: {
                    specs: 'tests/jasmine-standalone-2.0.0/spec/CommonSpec.js',
                    vendor: ['js/extlib.min.js', 'tests/jasmine-jquery/jasmine-jquery.js'],
                    helpers: ['js/utils.js', 'js/default.js'],
                    styles: 'css/common/page.min.css',
                    summary: true,
                    keepRunner: true
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            script: {
                files: ['js/default.js', 'js/utils.js'],
                tasks: ['jshint']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['css/common/page.css'],
                tasks: ['cssmin']
            },
            tests: {
                files: ['js/default.js', 'js/utils.js', 'tests/jasmine-standalone-2.0.0/spec/*.js'],
                tasks: ['jshint', 'jasmine']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'jasmine']);
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['cssmin', 'jshint', 'jasmine']);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
jasmine: {
    obpjs: {
        src: 'tests/jasmine-standalone-2.0.0/src/*.js',
        options: {
            specs: 'tests/jasmine-standalone-2.0.0/spec/CommonSpec.js',
            vendor: ['js/extlib.min.js', 'tests/jasmine-jquery/jasmine-jquery.js'],
            helpers: ['js/utils.js', 'js/default.js'],
            styles: 'css/common/page.min.css',
            summary: true,
            keepRunner: true,
            page: {
                viewportSize: {
                    width: 480,
                    height: 800
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html

Comment: Nope, I don't think it works. page object is not exposed in jasmine's options. The hacky way I found was to use "replace" module and manually configure the page object in grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/phantomjs/main.js

Comment: Worked fine for me. Thanks